# How to assign multiple key:value dicts into an already established dictionary, according to specific parameter

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, praw

Note: this makes use of a separate library called PRAW, which isn't critical to understanding the problem, and the ambiguous/related code has been annotated in my example below with `# !!!` to signify that the code is only necessary insofar as your need to understand that the code **produces a list of dicts**.

*Problem is a couple layers deep--will try my best to explain:

I have JSON data in `data.json`, which looks like so:

```
 {
   "USA":[
      {"shortlink":"https://short/74h13v"},
      {"responses":[]}
   ],
   "Vietnam":[
      {"shortlink":"https://short/74gyn4"},
      {"responses":[]}
   ],
   "Italy":[
      {"shortlink":"https://short/74h3i9"},
      {"responses":[]}
   ]
}
```

In the module(`scraper.py`), I have additional data which will come in the form of `comment.id="39dn28"`, `comment.body="this is a comment"`

I am attempting to insert multiple `comment.id` and `comment.body` instances into the `[]` attached to `responses` so that it looks like so:

```
{"responses": [
        {"39dn28": "this is my response"},
        {"39k229": "I'm another response"},
        {"35sn64": "another comment"} 
 ]}
```

Where it gets especially tricky for me is when I have to consider that each group of comments matches to the ID of a single country(or, 'shortlink'). And I've extracted the shortlink ID with `shortlinks = [data[link][0]["shortlink"][-6:] for link in data]` which results in `['74h3i9', '74gyn4', '74h13v']`.
Now I need to match each group of comments to its corresponding shortlink, and input those comments where they correctly belong.

Here is what I've tried so far, for insight into what I have and what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

shortlinks = [data[link][0]["shortlink"][-6:] for link in data]

for sl_id in shortlinks:
    # !!! (the following code produces a list of comment dicts.)
    submission = reddit.submission(id=sl_id)
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
    cmt_data = [{comment.id: comment.body} for comment in submission.comments.list()]

    for i in data:
        if sl_id in data[i][0]["shortlink"]:
            data[i][0]["responses"] = cmt_data

print(data)
```

This *almost* works.. For some reason I am also returned additional blank `'responses': []` and additional shortlinks.

Cannot seem to figure it out. Help much, much appreciated. I am open to alternate ways to accomplish it, and alternate ways to store the data(maybe not a list of dicts., etc.).

Comment: Are shortlinks unique across countries?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes, they are.

Comment: You probably need to remap `data` keying using short links. This will save you time going through data all over each time for every `sl_id` A quick fix tough is using `data[i][1]["responses"] = cmt_data`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get sth like this:

```
{
   "USA":[
  {"shortlink":"https://short/74h13v"},
  {"responses":[{},{},{}]}],...]

}
```

I think, it should be like this:

```
for sl_id in shortlinks:
# !!! (the following code produces a list of comment dicts.)
submission = reddit.submission(id=sl_id)
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
cmt_data = [{comment.id: comment.body} for comment in submission.comments.list()]

for i in data:
    if sl_id in data[i][0]["shortlink"]:
        data[i][1]["responses"] = cmt_data
```

Comment: Yes! Haha, and now I realize I've made the mistake of accessing the wrong item. :((. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in data.items():
    for x in value:
        if sl_id in x['shortlink']:
            if not 'responses' in x:
                x['responses'] = []
            x['responses'] += cmt_data
```

Comment: Try now, check now